# Cannot "Install New Software" in Eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have just installed Eclipse 3.5 for Java EE developers ("Galileo").

I need to add an extra plugin, but when I select the "Install New Software ..." menu item, nothing happens. Literally nothing - no dialog opens, no error message is displayed. If I have the Debug window open, no message are displayed.

If I go to Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites, that dialog opens OK, I can manage the list of update sites, and test the connections, and they all appear OK. But I cannot get to use them to actually install anything.

Is it just broken, or could there be something more subtle wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start by checking you **error log** under `Window -> Show View -> Error Log`. See if you're getting any exception while trying to install new software.

You can also install by downloading the plugin and unzipping it in the dropins folder.

Comment: Thanks, found the problem using the Error Log. There was an exeption when trying to launch that function. It turned out there were some read-only files in my installation which I think were stopping it from locking something.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue, with the same solution.  Not having the right files readable is a common side-effect of getting eclipse by a sync from a source code control system that leaves files which are not checked out as read-only by default.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem. There seems to be a bug related to the finish button (I am assuming this is the same problem you are experiencing). The way I got around it is by clicking on the finish button (or next, or whichever button is not working for you) and press the 'Enter' key. It's annoying. Seems to be an issue with how Eclipse is integrating with GTK.

Comment: Actually... after searching a little more I found a better solution to the problem. Set the following environment variable before starting eclipse.

GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true

Apparently there is some integration issue with the latest Gnome that is causing this odd behavior. Not sure if you are using Linux, but this did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, took a look at the error log and changed the launcher from "/usr/bin/eclipse" to "sudo /usr/bin/eclipse", it was a permissions thing...

Comment: yeah, but this is not very linuxy.  perhaps going to your eclipse directory and doing: sudo chmod -R [user].[user] . will assign everything back to you, and now eclipse cannot p0wn your whole machine.

Answer (score 1):

GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true also solved the non-clickable button problem for me running gnome 2.28.1 with Ubuntu Karmic (9.10) x64 with kernel 2.6.31-14-generic

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use **Eclipse Indigo (Eclipse 3.7)** which contains `EGit` already.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, I did the following:

1. Placed my copy of Eclipse in the trash
2. Emptied my trash
3. Rebooted my computer
4. Downloaded the latest version of Eclipse (which was Indigo at the time of writing)
5. Placed the .zip file in my applications folder
6. Double-clicked on the compressed zip to open it (I'm using Mac OS X.6)

The problem disappeared. I am now able to do **Help/Install new software...**.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try:

- Delete (rename/move) your workspace and try again. Be sure to backup all your projects and settings.
- Download the plugin "manually" and use `Eclipse>Window>Preferences>Install/Update>Available Software Sites` to add it locally.
- Download the plugin "manually" and use `Eclipse>Window>Help>Software Updates>Available Software>Add site>Archive`, find the directory on your HDD and add it.

Comment: Hi, creating a new workspace does not make any difference.

I've already got the plugin I want on disk locally, I just can't get it into Eclipse :-)  I can't see a way to actually add a plugin using the "Available Software Sites" dialog, only to configure the list of sites.

Comment: The Software Update you mention was replaced by "install new software" in Galileo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in windows... and spent couple of hours to "somehow" install the new softwares.

Anyway I will explain you how I managed to install it after trying many options..

1. Start a fresh copy of eclipse
2. First tick two check boxes(Show only latest version & Contact all update sites). Make sure the check box of group items is untick.
3. Try to add software...
   If not showing the list of plugins/Next buttons.
4. Delete the copy of eclipse.
5. Start a fresh copy of eclipse
6. Tick only the check box for Contact all update sites.
7. Now try to add plugins. It worked for me...

Even if it sounds crap... it worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I  had the exact the same problem. What I found out is that ***I installed the eclipse as root user***. Therefore, I need to be a root user in order to launch "Install New Software".

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions above work for you, simply **change the workspace to another location**. If the list of items appears properly then there's probably something screwed up in the workspace and not Eclipse. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just had a similar problem and wanted to offer the solution that worked for me.  This was not a permissions thing.  To solve that I always install eclipse as my user in my local directory (e.g. /home/[user]/local/eclipse-3.7.2) and then you never have permission issues.

Setup: Go to Help -> Install New software -> Available Software Sites (to add new site)

Symptom: Try to add a new site.  After hitting enter or clicking finish the site shows up in the list of available sites.  Click Okay to go back to the install new software and the site is not available in the drop down.  Go back to Available sites and the site is gone.

Fix: After adding the site click on the reload button while the new site is highlighted (before clicking Ok to go back to the "Install new software screen"

This was occurring on Indigo SR2 (and has been happening for a while).  I am running this on Linux Gtk -- but I don't see why this would be related.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Delete your ~/.eclipse folder and restart eclipse. This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

just press enter after entering URL in "Install new software" window

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. To troubleshoot this issue follow these steps:

1. Go to windows -> show view -> error.
2. Check the error logs. In my case error was    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available.    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.restore
3. I checked my config.ini which is under eclipse -> configuration folder.
4. I found eclipse.p2.data.area has incorrect path set.
5. I set the correct path for above key and restarted eclipse. It started working. 
   Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. To solve the problem, follow the following steps:

1. Window (Eclipse Menu) -> Show View -> Error Log
2. if Error Log is not there, then:
   Window (Menu) -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Error Log
3. Once the Error log is shown, Go to Help (Eclipse Menu) -> Install New Software
4. Check the Error log, most probable you will see an exception there.
5. Check the exception, most probable it's caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
6. Check the path mentioned in the exception, if you see ".Lock" in the path, close the eclipse then go to the path in windows machine and delete that folder.
7. now go to the eclipse "exe" file that you're using and open it as an administrator, then try, most probably this will solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I`m wondering if this [help](http://abdallao.blogspot.com/2010/04/eclipse-install-new-software-does-not.html) you.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Thanks but not for me, the answer for me was having read-only files in the file system, as per my comment of Nov 18. However this might be the problem for other people.