# Unable to Install EGit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I am trying to install EGit from [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#eclipseinstallation) tutorial. It says to add the plugin url in Help -> Install New Software.

Put In my Case I am not getting the add button on Install New Software dialog (see Image)[image: Install New Software Dialog].

My eclipse version is
[image]

Comment: Check the "Group items by category" checkbox on the install new software dialog box.

Comment: @Mark Elliot did that but not having Egit in that list :(

Comment: @jimmy: is it an Eclipse 3.4.2? If yes, it might be a bit old to support those p2 dialogs. Do you see the same issue with a more recent Eclipse? (even though a 3.5 can also have issue ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750222/cannot-install-new-software-in-eclipse-3-5 )

Comment: Download the new [Eclipse Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org)! Apparently it has built-in git support. I haven't tried it myself yet, but I hear people [love it](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/06/22/top-10-eclipse-indigo-features/)

Comment: @Thelper Thanks... But i dont want to change my eclipse any other way???

Comment: @Jimmy: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408961/upgrading-from-eclipse-galileo-to-helios/3409052#3409052 : you can make a *parallel* installation, leaving your current Eclipse untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a parallel Installation of Indigo as @VonC suggested.

Indigo already have EGIT :).