# Downloading a source from a git repository using eclipse?

Tags: windows, eclipse, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git plugin for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302089/git-plugin-for-eclipse)

I have a project on google code  to download. Is there a way I use `git clone project_url` in eclipse and download the source code?

Are there any plugins to do that? I'm using eclipse 3.4.2.

Comment: I asked it because it is not in stackoverflow.com!

Comment: Seriously? Google for "git eclipse" brings this SO question: [Git plugin for eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302089/git-plugin-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Egit Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)

You can add it to Eclipse from Eclipse Marketplace (Help-> Eclipse Market Place) and then import the Git Project using (File->Import->Git->Projects From Git) menu option

Comment: I don't have Eclipse Marketplace. i'm using 3.4.2. Do I have to manually install it?

Comment: @user601L It will be good you upgrade your Eclipse, the (Juno & Indigo) both have inbuilt GIT support using GIT. Based on the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502770/unable-to-install-egit-in-eclipse it looks it isn't possible for 3.4.2 (just remove 3 upgrade to 4.2 ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did it using Git for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find it here:
http://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Br,
Tim