# Eclipse "Install New Software" showing invisible lists

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, installation

The *Install New Software* option used for adding plug-ins has suddenly started to show "invisible" lists such that it's not possible to see what you're selecting. How could I fix this?

A few searches have shown that this may be linked to a bug with GTK but running `export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true` does not seem to fix the issue. One clue that something is wrong is this message in the terminal:

`** (Eclipse:2005): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion 'height >= -1' failed`

Comment: Programming tool questions should be posted on Stack Overflow, not on Programmers. I'm going to migrate this for you.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasOwens. Here is a related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750222/cannot-install-new-software-in-eclipse-3-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found a solution. If none of the solutions mentionned in the link on the comment above work for you then simply **change the workspace to another location**. If the list of items appears properly then there's probably an issue with the workspace you're using and not with Eclipse. Import your projects over and dispose of the old workspace.

Answer (score 11):

See [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355955#c16) link. I was successful in solving the same problem for myself.

> Blake Bond CLA 2012-05-24 10:56:37 EDT Deleting .metadata or .eclipse
>   folders is unacceptable of course, since it removes all workspace
>   customizations. Removing only the following two invalid settings
>   solved the problem for me.
>
> 1. Close Eclipse.
> 2. Find a file named .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui/dialog_settings.xml in
>      your workspace.
> 3. Open the file with a text editor and find a section named AvailableIUsPage.
> 4. Remove the following strings:
>      `<item value="0" key="AvailableVersionColumnWidth"/>
>      <item value="0" key="AvailableNameColumnWidth"/>`
> 5. Save the file and launch Eclipse.
>
> This is what triggers the bug in my case.
>
> 1. Help > Install New Software
> 2. Work with: Indigo
> 3. Entering any letter in the filter bar makes Eclipse hang with 100% CPU use for a minute or so.
> 4. If interrupted with ESC, the window simply disappears and there are no columns in available updates view after this anymore.
> 5. This dialog change is saved upon exit making the problem permanent.

Comment: Thanks. Copy-pasted the contents of the comment.

Answer (score 2):

see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2140183

I cannot use install new software using "help -> install new software" in Eclipse (both 4.2 and 3.8) after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04. The panel below the Name/Version bar appears to be missing (or too small) to list the available software. When scrolling on the side of the missing panel, it is possible to see a handful of rows of pixels change, which I believe are the items in the list of available software scrolling past. It is not possible tell for sure, however, becasue if the panel exists at all, it is likely only a few pixel rows high. This is true with both Eclicps 4.2 (which I installed manually) and Eclispe 3.8 (which I installed from the Ubuntu Software Center after removing Eclipse 4.2).

I have found two contributing factors to this problem. First, I noticed that the Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software window was not maximized. Maximinzing the window provided enough vertical height for item in the list to be displayed. I would prefer to see several items in the list, rather than only a single item in the list at a time, but at least it is possible to select packages to install. Second, I was using the defalt Nouveau display driver. I noticed that the computer screen scrolled when moving the cursor between the top and bottom of the screen. This occured because the Nouveau driver appartently cannot support my screen resolution (i.e., 1366 X 768). Installing the NVIDIA binary display driver and selecting the proper resolution eliminated the need for the screen to scroll.